# GPS is turning off when device is sleeping

Tags: android, service, gps, alarmmanager

I have built a tracking application which uses AlarmManager for periodic updates. I used a background service for this. The app is posting updates when the device is active and when it enters sleep mode, the GPS is automatically turning off and there were no more location updates. How could I keep the GPS on and get periodic location updates.